# Not able to open project from workspace

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I got one project. When In open that project from the workspace the pod section is looking blur, with red text. I not able to run the code, Getting the following issues
1.podfile.lock: no such file in directory
2. manifest .lock :no such file in dierctory.

I run the pod install and pod update commant. but I am not able to update it. Getting following error
"
Cloning spec repo `bitbucket-brapodspecs` from `git@bitbucket.org:BottleRocket/brapodspecs.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `git@bitbucket.org:BottleRocket/brapodspecs.git` named `bitbucket-brapodspecs`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`"

Please give me a solution.[image]

Comment: Show your podfile code

Comment: delete those files which are showing red from the project navigator

Comment: do pod repo add

Comment: Open Terminal -> type `cd <to your project path>`, then type `pod install` let it complete, then open the project, your project needs Pod libraries and workspace might be invalid.